# get timezone offset from UNIX timestamp in PHP

Tags: php, datetime, timezone

In PHP 7.2, if I do this:

```
<?php
$dt = new DateTime('@1522680410', new DateTimeZone(date_default_timezone_get())); 
$tz_offset = $exp->getOffset();
?>
```

$tz_offset always returns 0. However, if I set a date and not a UNIX timestamp (i.e., '2018-01-02' instead of '@1522680410') it shows the correct offset value.

Is there a way to have the timestamp return the timezone offset in one step like above?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently you can do it this way:

```
<?php
$dt = new DateTime(DateTime::createFromFormat('U', '1522680410')->format('Y-m-d'), new DateTimeZone(date_default_timezone_get()));
?>
```

Comment: With this solution you lose time part. And you don't need to set timezone to default, since default is already taken (no timezone definition in 1st parameter). Two DateTime object generation is an overkill.

Answer (score 1):

Unix timestamp is always in UTC timezone (or `±00:00` offset). If not, you are doing something nasty :)

If you take a look at [`DateTime::__construct()`](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.construct.php#refsect1-datetime.construct-parameters), you will see note on 2nd argument:

> The `$timezone` parameter and the current timezone are ignored when the `$time` parameter either is a UNIX timestamp (e.g. `@946684800`) or specifies a timezone (e.g. `2010-01-28T15:00:00+02:00`).

Change timezone after you have created DateTime object:

```
$dt = new DateTime('@1522680410');
$dt->setTimezone(new DateTimeZone(date_default_timezone_get()));
```